# Find Records inside same table by query with different where filters

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have this `sales` table:

```
ID  sid cid desciption  price   sdate
1   2   2   sadfsdf         177 11/12/2013
2   1   2   asdf            34  11/12/2013
3   2   2   asdsad          45  04/11/2013
```

(sid - salesmen id, cid - customer id, description - sales description , sdate - sales date)

I want to find 12th month's sales and find is there any sales done by same salesmen to same customer in previous month and display those records.

For example, from this table, output will be:

```
ID  sid cid desciption  price   sdate
1   2   2   sadfsdf         177 11/12/2013
3   2   2   asdsad          45  04/11/2013
```

This is MS Access database.

I have used this query, but no luck.

```
SELECT cid, 
       sid, 
       sdate 
FROM   sales 
WHERE  sdate > #12 / 01 / 2013 # 
       AND sdate < #12 / 31 / 2013 # 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT cid, 
                          sid, 
                          sdate 
                   FROM   sales 
                   WHERE  ( sdate > #11 / 01 / 2013 # 
                            AND sdate < #11 / 30 / 2013 # ) 
                          AND ( sales.sid = sales.sid 
                                AND sales.cid = sales.cid ))
```

Comment: I have used this query, but no luck ---
select cid,sid,sdate from sales 
where sdate > #12/01/2013# and sdate < #12/31/2013# AND  Exists 
( Select cid,sid,sdate from sales where (sdate > #11/01/2013# and sdate < #11/30/2013#) and (sales.sid=sales.sid and sales.cid=sales.cid) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer i found by my own..
thanks for everyone tried it and made effort to it...

```
SELECT cid, sid, sdate,price
FROM sales AS t1
WHERE sdate > #11/01/2013# and sdate < #11/30/2013# AND  Exists 
(Select cid,sid,sdate from sales as t2 where (sdate > #12/01/2013# and sdate < #12/30/2013#) and (t1.sid = t2.sid and t1.cid = t2.cid));
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GROUP BY` query to identify which salesmen/customer combinations occurred more than once in December.

```sql
SELECT
    s.sid,
    s.cid,
    Count(*) AS sales_count
FROM sales AS s
WHERE s.sdate BETWEEN #2013-12-01# AND #2013-12-31#
GROUP BY
    s.sid,
    s.cid
HAVING Count(*) > 1;
```

If you want to see those full sales records, join that query back to the `sales` table, by joining on `sid` and `cid` and applying the same `sdate` filter.

Comment: hi, thanks for effort. i just required to view all available duplicating records and i found solution.... :)